# Handling multiple views via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX requests (more specifically, jQuery's load method) to load different views within the same HTML DIV.

This works fine, but, some of these dynamically loaded pages have events hooked to them, for e.g. setTimeout, setInterval events, etc.

My question is: How do I handle the loading & unloading of these events across the loading of different views? Is there any specific pattern for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to just store data on each registered handler or timeout in an array. When loading a new view, these arrays would be looped and any listeners/timeouts removed before loading the new one.